# Integrating colorpicker into array field

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api, color-picker

I am using this code and i am trying to show a colorpicker onto an array field. Any ideas, how to do it?

```
<?php

class Smashing_Fields_Plugin {

    public function __construct() {
        // Hook into the admin menu
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'create_plugin_settings_page' ) );

        // Add Settings and Fields
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'setup_sections' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'setup_fields' ) );
    }

    public function create_plugin_settings_page() {
        // Add the menu item and page
        $page_title = 'My Awesome Settings Page';
        $menu_title = 'Awesome Plugin';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $slug = 'smashing_fields';
        $callback = array( $this, 'plugin_settings_page_content' );
        $icon = 'dashicons-admin-plugins';
        $position = 100;

        add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $slug, $callback, $icon, $position );
    }

    public function plugin_settings_page_content() {?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>My Awesome Settings Page</h2><?php
            if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) && $_GET['settings-updated'] ){
                  $this->admin_notice();
            } ?>
            <form method="POST" action="options.php">
                <?php
                    settings_fields( 'smashing_fields' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'smashing_fields' );
                    submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div> <?php
    }

    public function admin_notice() { ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p>Your settings have been updated!</p>
        </div><?php
    }

    public function setup_sections() {
        add_settings_section( 'our_first_section', 'My First Section Title', array( $this, 'section_callback' ), 'smashing_fields' );
        add_settings_section( 'our_second_section', 'My Second Section Title', array( $this, 'section_callback' ), 'smashing_fields' );
        add_settings_section( 'our_third_section', 'My Third Section Title', array( $this, 'section_callback' ), 'smashing_fields' );
    }

    public function section_callback( $arguments ) {
        switch( $arguments['id'] ){
            case 'our_first_section':
                echo 'This is the first description here!';
                break;
            case 'our_second_section':
                echo 'This one is number two';
                break;
            case 'our_third_section':
                echo 'Third time is the charm!';
                break;
        }
    }

    public function setup_fields() {
        $fields = array(
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_text_field',
                'label' => 'Sample Text Field',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => 'Some text',
                'helper' => 'Does this help?',
                'supplimental' => 'I am underneath!',
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_password_field',
                'label' => 'Sample Password Field',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'password',
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_number_field',
                'label' => 'Sample Number Field',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'number',
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_textarea',
                'label' => 'Sample Text Area',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'textarea',
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_select',
                'label' => 'Sample Select Dropdown',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => array(
                    'option1' => 'Option 1',
                    'option2' => 'Option 2',
                    'option3' => 'Option 3',
                    'option4' => 'Option 4',
                    'option5' => 'Option 5',
                ),
                'default' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_multiselect',
                'label' => 'Sample Multi Select',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'multiselect',
                'options' => array(
                    'option1' => 'Option 1',
                    'option2' => 'Option 2',
                    'option3' => 'Option 3',
                    'option4' => 'Option 4',
                    'option5' => 'Option 5',
                ),
                'default' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_radio',
                'label' => 'Sample Radio Buttons',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'radio',
                'options' => array(
                    'option1' => 'Option 1',
                    'option2' => 'Option 2',
                    'option3' => 'Option 3',
                    'option4' => 'Option 4',
                    'option5' => 'Option 5',
                ),
                'default' => array()
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_checkboxes',
                'label' => 'Sample Checkboxes',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'options' => array(
                    'option1' => 'Option 1',
                    'option2' => 'Option 2',
                    'option3' => 'Option 3',
                    'option4' => 'Option 4',
                    'option5' => 'Option 5',
                ),
                'default' => array()
            )
        );
        foreach( $fields as $field ){

            add_settings_field( $field['uid'], $field['label'], array( $this, 'field_callback' ), 'smashing_fields', $field['section'], $field );
            register_setting( 'smashing_fields', $field['uid'] );
        }
    }

    public function field_callback( $arguments ) {

        $value = get_option( $arguments['uid'] );

        if( ! $value ) {
            $value = $arguments['default'];
        }

        switch( $arguments['type'] ){
            case 'text':
            case 'password':
            case 'number':
                printf( '<input name="%1$s" id="%1$s" type="%2$s" placeholder="%3$s" value="%4$s" />', $arguments['uid'], $arguments['type'], $arguments['placeholder'], $value );
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                printf( '<textarea name="%1$s" id="%1$s" placeholder="%2$s" rows="5" cols="50">%3$s</textarea>', $arguments['uid'], $arguments['placeholder'], $value );
                break;
            case 'select':
            case 'multiselect':
                if( ! empty ( $arguments['options'] ) && is_array( $arguments['options'] ) ){
                    $attributes = '';
                    $options_markup = '';
                    foreach( $arguments['options'] as $key => $label ){
                        $options_markup .= sprintf( '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $key, selected( $value[ array_search( $key, $value, true ) ], $key, false ), $label );
                    }
                    if( $arguments['type'] === 'multiselect' ){
                        $attributes = ' multiple="multiple" ';
                    }
                    printf( '<select name="%1$s[]" id="%1$s" %2$s>%3$s</select>', $arguments['uid'], $attributes, $options_markup );
                }
                break;
            case 'radio':
            case 'checkbox':
                if( ! empty ( $arguments['options'] ) && is_array( $arguments['options'] ) ){
                    $options_markup = '';
                    $iterator = 0;
                    foreach( $arguments['options'] as $key => $label ){
                        $iterator++;
                        $options_markup .= sprintf( '<label for="%1$s_%6$s"><input id="%1$s_%6$s" name="%1$s[]" type="%2$s" value="%3$s" %4$s /> %5$s</label><br/>', $arguments['uid'], $arguments['type'], $key, checked( $value[ array_search( $key, $value, true ) ], $key, false ), $label, $iterator );
                    }
                    printf( '<fieldset>%s</fieldset>', $options_markup );
                }
                break;
        }

        if( $helper = $arguments['helper'] ){
            printf( '<span class="helper"> %s</span>', $helper );
        }

        if( $supplimental = $arguments['supplimental'] ){
            printf( '<p class="description">%s</p>', $supplimental );
        }

    }

}
new Smashing_Fields_Plugin();
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate some more and provide more code

Comment: Looks like you will need to define a colorpicker in your switch statement. Then you can reference that with a new array in your setup_fields method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real quick this should point you in the right direction, you need to define your colorpicker and then reference it, so like:

```
switch( $arguments['type'] ){
       case 'text':
       case 'password':
       case 'number':
       printf( '<input name="%1$s" id="%1$s" type="%2$s" placeholder="%3$s" value="%4$s" />', $arguments['uid'], $arguments['type'], $arguments['placeholder'], $value );
    break;
    case 'colorpicker':
       printf( '<input name="%1$s" id="%1$s" type="%2$s" placeholder="%3$s" value="%4$s" />', $arguments['uid'], $arguments['type'], $arguments['placeholder'], $value );
    break;
    ...
}
```

Then reference it in your `setup_fields` method:

```
public function setup_fields() {
        $fields = array(
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_text_field',
                'label' => 'Sample Text Field',
                'section' => 'our_first_section',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => 'Some text',
                'helper' => 'Does this help?',
                'supplimental' => 'I am underneath!',
            ),
            array(
                'uid' => 'awesome_color_picker',
                'label' => 'Sample colorpicker',
                'section' => 'our_whatever_section',
                'type' => 'colorpicker',
                'placeholder' => 'Some text',
                'helper' => 'Does this help?',
                'supplimental' => 'I am underneath!',
            ),
            ....
}
```